# How to get java output in shell

Tags: java, bash, shell

I have a shell script **run.sh** which is executing a jar file.

```
#!/bin/bash
"$JAVA_HOME"/bin/java -jar test.jar $1 $2 $3
```

After doing all the process in java I need to execute a command. So my java method calls a
shell script by passing it some arguments.

```
public static void Test(String Arg1, int Arg2, int Arg3, String Arg4) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            File currentLocation = new File(Test.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath());

            String executeShellScript = currentLocation.getParentFile().toString() + "/out.sh";

           //SOME LOGIC

            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/sh",executeShellScript,arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4);
            pb.redirectErrorStream(true);

            Process p = pb.start();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }

        }
```

And in my out.sh I take in the arguments and execute a command.

```
#!/bin/bash

IMAGE=$1
ROW=$2
COLUMN=$3
DESTINATION=$4
echo $IMAGE
```

I was wondering if I could execute and process the output of my jar from the same script (run.sh) by getting all the arguments?

Comment: won't just `"$JAVA_HOME"/bin/java -jar test.jar $1 $2 $3 > test.txt` work?

Comment: The problem is one of the output args is several 1000 lines of file path. Writing and reading it from a text file might increase the computation time. What do you think ?

Comment: Writing and reading from a file is faster than doing it in the console. Try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect the output of your jar in a file  (>out.txt after your $3 in run.sh) and process that file in run.sh. or you can pipe (|) the output.

Comment: The problem is one of the output args is several 1000 lines of file path. Writing and reading it from a text file might increase the computation time. I might be wrong here.

Comment: System.out.print(arg1,"|","arg2");
and use shell script to parse this?

Comment: No, in your run.sh after $3 you can pipe the output to a shell command, instead of redirecting.